# Swift: Document files gets deleted when building the app

Tags: ios, swift

I have a strange issue that every time i build the app my downloaded files in document directory are deleted so i have to download them again. It happens only when i build the app and I am not deleting the files when app is killed and open it again.

You happen to know why ?

This is my code for downloading files

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: request) { tempLocalUrl, _, error in
        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
            let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let documentName = "documentName" + "." + url.pathExtension
            let destinationURL = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(documentName)
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationURL.path) {
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationURL)
                } catch {
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Comment: Try to `print(error)` inside `catch` instead of `return`

Comment: How do you know the files were deleted?

Comment: Your app is sandboxed. Every time you run your app it will be in a different location.

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, but so far the OP has not shown evidence of saving the file locations beyond the app run. That's why I asked "how do you know"; there must be more going on than we are being shown.

Comment: I am showing this files in the app. I store the paths with CoreData and when I build again and want to see those files, FileManager is saying that those paths don't exist.

Comment: "I store the paths with CoreData" Yup, that's exactly the problem. Your files do in fact persist between builds. They are not deleted at all. The trouble is the paths do not persist, so your saved paths are useless; they cannot "find" the files.

Comment: Bro, have you found any solution, I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You check for existing file AFTER the download has been completed. This will always download the file; it just doesn't copy the file if destination already exists.

Correct code looks like this:

```
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationURL.path) {
   // Download the file
}
```

Of course, you need to decide the file name before downloading.